# Return Multiple Values with REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

Lets say I have a class named 'Shows' that is supposed to hold the data for an event that will occur that the user is planning to attend.  However a user can attend more than one show, is there a way to create an array,list or collection and return these so they can be processed by ajax and turned into json?

```
 Models.Shows show = new Models.Shows();
 show.id = 1;
 show.Image = "my_image.jpg";
 show.Location = "Boston";
 show.Name = "Boston Event";

 if (show.Success())
     return Ok(show);
```

Essentially, I want to create a collection to return more than one of these 'show' variables.

Current Result

```
<Shows xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AppServices1.Models">
<Date i:nil="true"/>
<Image>my_image.jpg</Image>
<Location>Boston</Location>
<Name>Boston Event</Name>
<id>1</id>
</Shows>
```

Desired Result

```
<Shows xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AppServices1.Models">
<Show>
    <Date i:nil="true"/>
    <Image>my_image.jpg</Image>
    <Location>Boston</Location>
    <Name>Boston Event</Name>
    <id>1</id>
</Show>
<Show>
    <Date i:nil="true"/>
    <Image>my_image.jpg</Image>
    <Location>Boston</Location>
    <Name>Boston Event</Name>
    <id>1</id>
</Show>
<Show>
    <Date i:nil="true"/>
    <Image>my_image.jpg</Image>
    <Location>Boston</Location>
    <Name>Boston Event</Name>
    <id>1</id>
</Show>
</Shows>
```

---Edit----
Okay, I can admit I'm stupid, if anyone runs into the same problem, Just use an actual list...

Final Result

```
<ArrayOfShows xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AppServices1.Models">
<Shows>
    <Date i:nil="true"/>
    <Image>my_image.jpg</Image>
    <Location>Boston</Location>
    <Name>Boston Event</Name>
    <id>1</id>
</Shows>
<Shows>
    <Date i:nil="true"/>
    <Image>my_image.jpg</Image>
    <Location>Boston</Location>
    <Name>Boston Event</Name>
    <id>1</id>
    </Shows>
<Shows>
<Date i:nil="true"/>
<Image>my_image.jpg</Image>
<Location>Boston</Location>
<Name>Boston Event</Name>
<id>1</id>
</Shows>
</ArrayOfShows>
```

Comment: Do you want JSON or XML ? You should be able to just return an array of Show (`Show[]`) to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Have you actually tried to return a collection of `Models.Show`?

Comment: ... I guess i can just add this to my list of fails for today.  Thanks for the help, No idea how I over sighted this when I was imagining using the list to explain the question -.-